# Passar a Session com Node.JS

Tags: node.js, aplicação-web, angular

Oi, estou com uma dificuldade com a session numa aplicação com nodejs e angular 4.

Estou fazendo dessa forma:

Ao digitar o e-mail e senha na tela de login e dar submit no formulário de login, cria um http request, que é tipo um ajax, ele passa os campos por método POST.
Node pega essa requisição, usa a fuction login do mongoose que está na controller usuarios, se o login é valido ele insere um boolean dizendo que  essa session existe (chamada de exist), id, nome e sobrenome na session da requisição.

Depois ele retorna essa variável pro "ajax", ai o angular salva essa variável no serviço, depois verifica com o boolean exist pra ver se a session existe, se sim ele manda pro bashboard.

No dashboard é feito um getSession, que nada mais é que pegar o atributo session que foi salvo no login.

Até ai tudo certo, aparece o nome da pessoa, pois na tela do dashboard diz "Olá, nomeDaPessoa", mas quando dou F5 para atualizar a página some o nome da pessoa, estou com dificuldade para identificar o por que some o nome da pessoa, pode ser algum problema no mongo ou na session?

Comment: De uma olhada [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29823558/5429980).

Comment: Dei uma editada na minha pergunta.

Comment: O F5 recarrega tudo do 0, a menos que você envie um token do login e verificar se está expirado ou não e retornar os dados do usuário. Ou pense em outro método, como localStorage ou sessionStorage, ou outra alternativa.